# Trying to append a range to the last row of a separate sheet - Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am running this function that saves simulated data from another sheet. These ranges are the data that I want saved to the last row of another sheet. So for instance if I run the sim today 12/19 - I want the data to be appended to the last row after the sim data I ran yesterday 12/18.

Problems:

1.It doesn't copy the entire range of "B5:L6" it copy's C5:G6 or something like that

2. It doesn't append the rows downward, it moves the items down and copy's the last range to the first row IE 10,9,8,7 instead of 7,8,9,10

Any direction with this would be very much appreciated

```
function saveSimData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('Avery Sim 2.0');
  var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Test2");
  var simDataList = s.getRangeList(['B5:L6', 'B7:L8','B9:L10','B11:L12','B13:L14','B15:L16','B17:L18','B19:L20','B21:L22','B23:L24','B25:L26','B27:L28','B29:L30','B31:L32','B33:L34']);
  var simData = simDataList.getRanges();
  var numGames = s.getRange('N10').getValue();
  var lastRow = destSheet.getLastRow();
  for (var i=0;i<numGames;i++){
    destSheet.insertRowAfter(lastRow);
    simData[i].copyTo(destSheet.getRange(lastRow +1,2), {contentsOnly:true});
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please redact any confidential details and share a copy of the spreadsheet with us?

Comment: No, I am sorry but I cannot.

Answer (score 1):

```
function saveSimData() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var s=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var ds=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var simDataList=['B5:L6', 'B7:L8','B9:L10','B11:L12','B13:L14','B15:L16','B17:L18','B19:L20','B21:L22','B23:L24','B25:L26','B27:L28','B29:L30','B31:L32','B33:L34'];
  var oA=[];
  for(var i=0;i<simDataList.length;i++) {
    var vA=s.getRange(simDataList[i]).getValues();//get data from each range  
    for(var j=0;j<vA.length;j++) {
      oA.push(vA[j]);//append each row to output array
    }
  }
  ds.getRange(ds.getLastRow()+1,5,oA.length,oA[0].length).setValues(oA);
}
```

or if you wish to use a RangeList instead:

```
function saveSimData() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var s=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var ds=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var sDL=s.getRangeList(['B5:L6', 'B7:L8','B9:L10','B11:L12','B13:L14','B15:L16','B17:L18','B19:L20','B21:L22','B23:L24','B25:L26','B27:L28','B29:L30','B31:L32','B33:L34']);
  var sRL=sDL.getRanges();
  var oA=[];
  for(var i=0;i<sRL.length;i++) {
    var vA=sRL[i].getValues();//get data from each  range  
    for(var j=0;j<vA.length;j++) {
      oA.push(vA[j]);//append each row to output array
    }
  }
  ds.getRange(ds.getLastRow()+1,5,oA.length,oA[0].length).setValues(oA);
}
```

Comment: This still produces the 10 row of the sim on the first open row of the other sheet. I want them to basically be copied and pasted, but there are different amounts of games for each date. So if there is a way to count the rows that are not blank from sheet one and post to the first open row in sheet two that would be optimal. I appreciate your help!

Comment: You use terms like `sim` and `games` and `for each date` and you speak of rows that are not blank but what  you don't seem to understand is that you and I don't share the same context because I don't have your spreadsheet.  So if you can't share the spreadsheet then you have to be more specific about how data is supposed to be distributed.